# Rounding difference between1 and 2 decimal places

Tags: go

[Ed: reworded - sorry for the confusing initial wording. Also thanks to all those who suggested using integers, but for several reasons I must use `float64`.]

I have a floating point value that I want to round to 1 decimal if more than 100 and no decimals if more than 1000, otherwise round to 2 decimals.  This works:

```
func r(f float64) float64 {
    if f >= 999.5 {
        return math.Round(f)
    }
    if f >= 99.95 {
        return math.Round(f*10) / 10
    }
    return math.Round(f*100) / 100
}
```

but I'm wondering if this would be better:

```
func r(f float64) float64 {
    if f >= 999.5 {
        return math.Round(f)
    }
    if f*10 >= 999.5 {  // **** only changed line ****
        return math.Round(f*10) / 10
    }
    return math.Round(f*100) / 100
}
```

This is safer as 99.95 is not represented exactly using floating point with a binary exponent. (I believe the Go language requires use of IEEE fp format which has a binary exponent.) 999.5 *is* exactly representable as a fp value.

However, my tests (using `math.NextAfter()`) show that the first solution works perfectly well for all values from 99.94999999 to 99.95000001. 1st question: I am worrying unduly.

The problem with the 2nd solution is that I am worried that `f*10` may be evaluated twice. 2nd question: is there any guarantee the optimiser will ensure that it is only done once.

Comment: Neither is really safer, because you should not be using floating point arithmetic for decimal values like currency.

Comment: A simple approach is to store currency as an `int` of cents, which avoids the imprecision of floats, and leave decimal point placement entirely to a *rendering* concern (which it is).

Comment: Using the minimal unit for the currency is a common approach, as Bohemian says, just keep in my that different currencies have different fractions for the minimal unit (or none at all like JPY).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken. There is no way to solve the problem you're trying to solve using binary floating point.

Comment: Thanks @JimB for you reply:
> neither is really safe...
Actually I know that the 2nd is perfectly safe as it use the same rounding as `Round`.  Moreover 999.5 does not have rounding problems.  The question was about the optimizer - ie whether I can be sure that f*10 is not evaluated twice at runtime.

I thoroughly understand fp rounding problems and that in general  it should not be used for currency.  However, the value is being given to me by a package that I have no control over.  Moreover, 999.5 is represented exactly in a fp rep. (whether using binary or decimal exponent).

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian. My problem is actually not about rendering (sorry to mislead you with my mention of display of numbers but that was the easiest way I could think to describe the problem).  Also the money value is not currency per se (again confusing) but odds in a gambling app - effectively a money value.  I've reworded the question to avoid the confusion.

Comment: "odds in a gambling app" doesn't sound like currency to me. Nevertheless, it *does* sound like a float type is not suitable. Perhaps use "cents" (which comes from the latin *centum*, meaning "hundred") as "1 hundredth of a percentage (also from *centum*) then your conditions would be simple `int` comparisons.

Comment: @Bohemian I *never* mentioned currency (that was @JimB).  I said "money value" originally but removed that as confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about the extra multiplication, rather than rely on the optimizer, you can pull it out this way:

```
func r(f float64) float64 {
    if f >= 999.5 {
        return math.Round(f)
    }
    
    f *= 10
    if f >= 999.5 {
        return math.Round(f) / 10
    }
    
    f *= 10
    return math.Round(f) / 100
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob Napier that is a very good point.  (I must have had a brain failure.)

Comment: @AJR: also note that divides are usually an oder of magnitude more expensive, so while this is better code organization, the concern about the second multiple is likely misplaced.

Comment: @JimB you are right that a further improvement would be to use  * 0.1  instead of  / 10 .  I guess I was really most interested about what guarantees are given about optimisation in Go.

Comment: @AJR: the language makes no guarantees about the compiler optimizations.